# Does a bios flash count as a CMOS reset?

Tags: cmos

Does a BIOS reflash count as a CMOS reset, I would like to know because I cannot get new ram to work on my laptop which worked on it before. I would not like to clear the CMOS...

Short backstory:

I had my laptop get taken to repair the day before the warrenty expired as I spilled milk on the components (Whole computer worked except for keyboard). I took the ram out that I am trying to put in now before we sent it off to repair and took out any upgrades such as SSD and WLAN chips as we were trying to hide that we voided the warranty (We got away with it). The laptop came back, I instantly noticed a speed improvement and better temperature management. All the greatness ended when I found that the ram I had that I took out no longer was supported. I even tried with a replica same result..

More info:

I went to go reflash the bios without having the new ram inserted to get the latest version for stability. I then replaced the hard drive with a SSD, as well as inserting the new ram stick. Booted it up and reloaded all the settings, restarted it 3 times to make sure all the drivers on the new machine were now ready-to-install on the SSD (which by the way was being used in another laptop). I used a special tool to install the drivers, uninstall useless / unsupported ones, and install all the dependencies for the new drivers. Played around with it for a while to find out that I had 4GB of ram loaded instead of 8GB, and here we are now.

Comment: Why not try to clear the CMOS, which is the first step in troubleshooting this kind of issue?  If that doesn't work, you'll need to provide details on your BIOS version (before and after update), motherboard model, and RAM specs.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I am on a laptop, and I just got it back from repair. If you feel me you wouldn't want to take it completely apart after a repair.

Comment: No, don't open it.  Just go in the BIOS setup and reset it to default settings to see if it solves your RAM issue.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I have tried that, no help.. Any other possible way? Because this worked completely fine before.

Comment: I suspect that the technically correct answer is that it could be system-dependent; in some cases, the BIOS flash procedure may affect the CMOS.  Regardless of whether that's accurate, adjusting the BIOS code may affect how the CMOS data is interpreted.  That is probably not the case, usually, but it could be.  You should not count on your CMOS settings being saved by the computer.  Instead, manually write down any settings of concern.  Your Mobo manual might document default settings, so you might want to just write down the non-defaults.

Comment: @SkorrloreGaming-Productions: As I mentioned at first, if it doesn't resolve it, then we need details to identify what could cause it.  Did you take this update in the laptop's manufacturer's website or elsewhere?  What version did you have before and did you upgrade it to?  What is the model number of the laptop and RAM chips that are not detected?

Comment: @SkorrloreGaming-Productions:  It might be interesting to know what your computer tech did to it too.

Comment: @JuliePelletier The repair men completely replaced the motherboard, but with the exact same one. They also replaced the hard drive and cover. I myself reflashed the bios before I wrote down the current one (but it was 2. something, it is now 3.0.0). It is an ASUS X550CA laptop, the ram chip I am trying to insert is toshiba branded but it worked completely fine before the repair men replaced the motherboard.

Comment: @JuliePelletier It might also be something to note is that I had the new ram out when I reflashed, also I replaced the hard drive with an ssd after the reflash. All within 2 days of getting it back from repair.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Hello? I added tons of information to the question.

Comment: Is your OS 64bits and is the memory detected at the BIOS level?

Comment: @JuliePelletier Yes, and no

Comment: Then we'll need the bios version change, if you got it on the laptop manufacturer's website, your laptop's model number and the RAM model number.  Without those, there's nothing else to do here.

Comment: How many RAM slots do you have, and how many chips/sticks did you add?  Assuming you have two slots, you might try swapping the RAM stick(s) to the other slot(s).

Comment: @WesLarson I got 1 onboard and one removable, I am trying to put it into the removable slot.

Comment: Update, it seems to be working now out of the blue. I tried putting the ram stick in now and it works, but I have changed nothing. really.. I haven't reflashed the bios, used a different ram stick.. nothing. Anyhow it seems to be fixed and thanks for trying to help me resolve the issue when it was going on.